# How to display or console.log messages in react from express.js?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a working login/register function with jwt and all, but I don't know how could I log a message in react that comes from back-end.
I've tried using  `if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send(console.log("user already exists"));`, but that doen't work. And if I use `if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password');`, then it also doens't dislay anything. I use axios and cors to connect react with node.js. And whenever I fill out a form in front-end, it actually stores the user in mongodb database.
Here is the code for the signup component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  FormWrap,
  Icon,
  FormContent,
  Form,
  FormH1,
  FormLabel,
  FormInput,
  FormButton,
  Text,
} from "./SignupElements";
import axios from 'axios';

const Signup = () => {

  const [registerUsername, setRegiserUsername] = useState("");
  const [registerPassword, setRegiserPassword] = useState("");
  const [registerEmail, setRegiserEmail] = useState("");

  function register() {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      data: {
        username: registerUsername,
        password: registerPassword,
        email: registerEmail
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/user/signup"
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.data){
        alert('user saved!');
      }
    }).catch (err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <FormWrap>
        <Icon to="/">Amp Beats</Icon>
        <FormContent>
          <Form>
            <FormH1>Create an account</FormH1>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Email</FormLabel>
            <FormInput type="email" onChange={e => setRegiserEmail(e.target.value)}></FormInput>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Username</FormLabel>
            <FormInput type="username" onChange={e => setRegiserUsername(e.target.value)}></FormInput>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Password</FormLabel>
            <FormInput type="password" onChange={e => setRegiserPassword(e.target.value)}></FormInput>
            <FormButton type="button" onClick={register}>Create Accout</FormButton>
            <Text>WARNING: Do not enter your real password or email, because if it gets leaked, I will probably be too lazy to fix it.</Text>
          </Form>
        </FormContent>
      </FormWrap>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

The alert actually works, but whenever I try to log the error and I check the console, I see this: Error:

```
Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

And if I check it with postman, all the messages are getting displayed.

Comment: You can console.log the response of the backend in your React App, or console.log in your backend but you'll see the log in the terminal where the server runs not in the browser

Comment: Instead of alert try console.log(res), check it gives

Comment: A basic Express tutorial might be a good starting point.